# Constraintlayout bug Android Studio

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I was happily developing on Android (making some design) when I moved a button up in hierarchy and everything got weird. I'm using Constraintlayout for better alignment.

[image]

As you can see, on the blue screen there's no two buttons neither Guidelines.
I tried to rebuild but some NonInfo Nullpointer appeared

[image]

Any suggestion? Do I have to re-do everything from scratch?

Info: I was editing it on Landscape before this happened

Comment: constraint layout is still in beta .

Comment: They will fix soon.. Pls rise this bug to Google.

Comment: can you show xml code ?

Answer (score 0):

If you could post your XML, that would be helpful. Which version of ConstraintLayout are you using? Also, you should check out Android Studio 2.3, we made a ton of improvements in the layout editor.